# Rails Devise: how do I place the login form and the recover password on the same page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My template looks like this:

```
.dropdown.light
      .login
        =form_for("user", :url => user_session_path) do |f|
          = f.hidden_field :redirect_to, :value => request.fullpath
          = f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "email", :size => ''
          = f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "password", :size => ''
          div.remember
            = f.check_box :remember_me, :checked => "checked"
            = f.label :remember_me
          .clearfix
            a.forgot.pull-left href="#forgot" Forgot your password?
            input.pull-right type="submit" value="Sign in"
      .forgotten
        =form_for(:user,:as => :user_forgot, :url => password_path(:user), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f|
          p
            strong Reset your password
          p.small Give us your e-mail and you’ll be back in a jiffy
          div= f.email_field :email
          .clearfix
            a.forgot.nevermind.pull-left href="#forgot" Nevermind
            input.pull-right type="submit" value="Reset password"
      .sent
        p
          strong Email sent!
        p In a couple of minutes you should receive an email with a link to reset your password
```

It actually works, but it generates two forms with duplicate ids such as...

```
<input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email">
```

How do I change this so the IDs don't duplicate?

Comment: You can overwrite input params as usual: `f.email_field :email, :id => 'forgot_email'`

Comment: Do you need to show both form on same page or same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add namespace to your forms.

```
=form_for(:user, :as => :user_forgot, :url => password_path(:user), :namespace => 'forgot', :html => { :method => :post }) do |f|
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like involving namespaces, you can try an AJAX request. This will guarantee that you can rename fields while forming a POST request.

Or you can override a default PasswordsController of Devise and write own method to recover password. For your override you can simply borrow the code of some methods from {RubyFolder}/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb and change it slightly for your application (for example, rename expected input parameters).